# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'select' of null in magento admin customer grid

Tags: magento-1.7, javascript, prototype-js

`I know there were similar problems like this but each and every problem is different.`

I `recently move my site to new server.`

After that i am getting `error(console)` in `magento customer grid.`

Error is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'select' of null` and accordian is also not loading properly.

I get this error `after i click on each customer.`

May be for this reason `i am getting 500 internal server error on that page`.

[image]

***Memory limit is given in .htaccess in 512MB & 
   permission is given 777 to all js->mage->adminhtml***

Comment: Check your HTML code, this page doesn't look like completly loaded. You don't have a JS error, you have a PHP Error. Please have a look in the [great debugging tutorial](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store) and report back.

Comment: i have not dont any changes in html of that part..thats purely base magento loaded. And how can you say its php error? while i am getting js error in chrome console ..see the screenshot above

Comment: I saw the screenshot and there is the whole part on the right side missing. This happens, when a PHP error occurs. How can you say, there is no PHP error, when you haven't checked the source? Please have a look into your source.

Comment: I am not telling that there is no php errors..but i am getting confused how that can be..same file is running in other server..and there its running fine..even we have not done any changes on that part( php, html ,js)...Total right side is missing and accordian also not loaded after billing agreements..thanks for help..i am trying to find the php errors

Comment: How about apache error.log?

Comment: This happens, because files are missing after copying, rights for the files and directories are wrong, cache can not be written, cache is from the old server and is wrong, so many possibilities what can get wrong when you move your installation...

Comment: Hey after enabling developer mode true and show errors i got this Warning: Division by zero  in lib/Zend/Cache/Backend/Libmemcached.php on line 395

Comment: Thats a filling percentage error for memcache. Try flushing the memcache and check the memcache configuration on your new server.

Comment: its solved..mcrypt was not installed..that was creating the problem..thanks to everyone

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt  hey i have asked a question on here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23241869/static-custom-options-in-magento  if you want to answer.. it will be helpful